# How to add external npm packages to phonegap?

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, npm, ibm-watson

How can I add external `npm` packages to phonegap? In my phonegap application, I need to add `IBM Watson Speech To Text` node.js package, which you can find here - http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/speech-to-text/api/v1/?node#

I know I have to download it by `npm install watson-developer-cloud` but after that what should I do so it will be accessible in phonegap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to run the `watson-developer-cloud` npm module in PhoneGap because it can't run in the browser.

We are working (see [this](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-sdk/issues/225)) on restructuring the module to run in the browser. In the meantime, if you are trying to use the Speech to Text service in PhoneGap use the [`watson-speech`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/watson-speech) module which has the Speech To Text and Text to Speech APIs.